# Why won't my query in a dynamic SQL work as intended?

Tags: sql, ssms

I believe I have a formatting problem in the query but I need a second set of eyes to help me please.

```
select @InsertSQL = ' Insert Into #ResultSet('
    +   'UserDomainMappingId,'
    +   'UserId,'
    +   'UserName,'
    +   'Domain,'
    +   'DomainName,'
    +   'LastUpdatedBy,'
    +   'LastUpdatedByName,'
    +   'LastUpdatedAt)'

select @SelectSQL = ' select '
    +   'UD.UserDomainMappingId,'
    +   'UD.UserId,'
    +   '(select FullName from Users where UserId = UD.UserId),'
    +   'UD.Domain,'
    +   '(select Name from ReferenceCodes RC where RC.Type = ''DOMAIN'' and RC.Code = ''' + @Domain + '''),'
    +   'UD.LastUpdatedBy,'
    +   '(select FullName from Users where UserId = UD.LastUpdatedBy),'
    +   'UD.LastUpdatedAt'                              

    select @FromSQL = ' from UserDomainMapping UD '

    select @WhereSQL = 'where UserDomainMappingId = UD.UserDomainMappingId '
```

I'm expecting:

the select for DomainName to work, as it does if I remove the quotes and hardcode the scaler, but it doesn't inside the dynamic sql. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `where UserDomainMappingId = UD.UserDomainMappingId` equivalent to `1=1` or did i miss something?

Comment: Use a `PRINT` statement to generate the final query, then copy it into a query window to determine where your error is.

Comment: Just recreate your code, and seems ok for me, unless I forgot to initiate @Domain. If it's value is `NULL`, then `@SelectSQL` will be `null` too

Comment: Why are yo using dynamic SQL?  IT does not seem necessary.

Comment: What is the actual problem? You say you expect "the select for DomainName to work", so what is actually happening? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: When I run the procedure I get  a null query. If I comment out the DomainName insert and select, the query runs fine. I have I take the DomainName select and take out the quotes from the dynamic sql and hardcode the scalar value(running in a blank procedure) it returns what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating string in SQL has a tendency to `NULL` the result if any of the values is `NULL`. Made a little example you can try:

```
declare @A varchar(100), @B varchar(100), @C varchar(100)

set @A = 'a'
set @B = 'b'
set @C = @A + @B 
select @C --'ab' 

set @A = null
set @B = 'b'
set @C = @A + @B 
select @C --NULL 

set @A = 'a'
set @B = null
set @C = @A + @B 
select @C --NULL 

set @A = 'a'
set @B = null
set @C = @A + isnull(@B ,'')
select @C --'a'
```

So, basically you get an empty query, because @Domain is `NULL`. For that I suggest to use `isnull(@Domain,'')`

Comment: I overlooked that @Domain is Null. It Shouldn't be and that's the problem. Thank you.